# Illegal constraint in a superclass context (GHC 8.0.1)

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, type-families

So I have this code that throws an error I can't find any information on. Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module Main where
import Network.Google

class ( HasScope '["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"] a
      , GoogleRequest a) 
      => IsRequest a
```

Here's the error:

```
• Illegal constraint ‘HasScope
                    '["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"]
                    a’ in a superclass context
(Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
• In the context: (HasScope
                 '["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"] a,
               GoogleRequest a)
While checking the super-classes of class ‘IsRequest’
In the class declaration for ‘IsRequest’
```

What's going on here? I'm using GHC 8.0.1.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the definition of `HasScope`?

Comment: @ReidBarton It appears to come from [`Network.Google`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-0.1.1/docs/Network-Google.html#t:HasScope) in the *gogol* package.

Comment: Thanks, I found a different `Network.Google` module first.

Comment: Just enable `UndecidableInstances` as suggested. It's a type family, and in the presence of type families, GHC cannot easily guarantee termination. See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#the-constraint-kind for a little bit more info.

Comment: Surely it's a bit surprising that GHC is telling us to turn on `UndecidableInstances` when we haven't written any instances yet.